# Creation of SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query issue ..
Basically in my hotel booking website there is Reservations
the reservation has a **Check in date** and a **Check out date**

.

I need an SQL query which

> detects if a new **check in** and **checkout date** is in the range of any
>   **check in** and **check out date** in the table.

My current query  doesn't work because it doesn't detect when a newly entered check in date starts before the database checkin date and a newly entered checkout date finishes after the checkout date in the database.

Thanks for your help!

**Current Code ( I wasnt sure if you wanted it in pure sql or ...**

```
// Gets the Checkin and checkout dates from the session variable
        $FirstDate = $request->session()->get('checkin');
        $SecDate = $request->session()->get('checkout');

        // Tries to match the checkin and checkout dates with other reservations of the same Hotel room
        foreach ($Rooms as $Room) {
            $Id =  $Room->id;

            $RoomsBooked = Reservation::where('room_id','=', $Id)
            ->where('CheckIn','>=',$FirstDate)
            ->where('CheckOut','<=',$SecDate)

                ->orWhere(function($query) use ($FirstDate,$Id)
                    {
                      $query->where('room_id','=', $Id)
                            ->where('CheckIn','<=',$FirstDate)

                            ->where('CheckOut','>=',$FirstDate);
                          })

                            ->orWhere(function($query2) use ($FirstDate,$SecDate,$Id)
                            {
                              $query2->where('room_id','=', $Id)
                                    ->where('CheckIn','>=',$FirstDate)

                                    ->where('CheckIn','<=',$SecDate);
                                  })->count();


                  // Works out How many rooms are available
                  $Roomsavailable = $Room->TotalRooms;
                  $Roomsleft =  $Roomsavailable - $RoomsBooked;
                  $Room->spaceleft = $Roomsleft;
            }
```

Comment: Edit your question and show your current query.

Comment: update your question and  add a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: show some rows in your table and the expected result in a tabular format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic logic to check whether two date ranges overlap is simply:

```
where start1 < end2 and end1 > start2
```

Replace `<` with `<=` etc. if you want the same date to count as overlap.

So, within your code, I think you just need a *single* place that checks:

```
        ->where('CheckIn','<=',$SecondDate)
        ->where('CheckOut','>=',$FirstDate);
```

Comment: Wow , thanks dude , that works +1 for cleaning up my code too!